# управление отрисованным прямоугольником с клавиатуры

Tags: java, swing

Как реализовать управление прямоугольником (пакет `graphics2d`, `drawRect()`) через клавиатуру, и чтобы он мог не только двигаться, но и поворачиваться (wsad и стрелки соответственно)?
функция отрисовки прямоугольника:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
  Graphics2D gty = (Graphics2D) g;
  g2d.drawRect(rob_body_x, rob_body_y, rob_body_length, rob_body_width);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот накидал пример, изучайте, задавайте вопросы.

> Идея в том что по нажатию и опусканию клавиш плавно меняется скорость движения или поворота в определенном направлении.

А во время отрисовки скорость умножается на время, прошедшее с прошлого кадра, для обеспечения равномерного перемещения между кадрами, которые по факту могут отрисовываться в разное время.

Логика перемещения вот:

```
Action action = actions.get(key);

if (action.pressed)
   action.speed = Math.min(action.speed + dt, 1);

else if (action.speed > 0)
   action.speed = Math.max(action.speed - dt, 0);

float dir = key == KeyEvent.VK_W || key == KeyEvent.VK_D ? 1 : -1;

if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W || key == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
    y += Math.sin(r) * action.speed * dir;
    x += Math.cos(r) * action.speed * dir;
}

if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A || key == KeyEvent.VK_D)
    r += action.speed / 30 * dir;
```

А вот отрисовка, сначала мы двигаем и поворачиваем контекст, а потом рисуем прямоугольник:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
g2d.setRenderingHints(rh);
g2d.clearRect(0,0, 10000, 10000);
g2d.translate(x + w/2, y + h/2);
g2d.rotate(r);
g2d.translate(-w/2, -h/2);
g2d.fillRect(0, 0, (int) w, (int) h);
```

```js
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Rect extends JPanel implements KeyListener{

    RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(
            RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    private class Action {
        boolean pressed;
        float speed;
    }

    long t = 0;
    float x = 100;
    float y = 100;
    float w = 40;
    float h = 60;
    float r = 0;

    Map<Integer, Action> actions = new HashMap<Integer, Action>(){{
        put(KeyEvent.VK_W, new Action());
        put(KeyEvent.VK_S, new Action());
        put(KeyEvent.VK_A, new Action());
        put(KeyEvent.VK_D, new Action());
    }};

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        tick();
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHints(rh);
        g2d.clearRect(0,0, 10000, 10000);
        g2d.translate(x +w/2, y+h/2);
        g2d.rotate(r);
        g2d.translate(-w/2, -h/2);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, (int)w, (int) h);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    private void tick() {
        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        float dt = (millis - t) / 300f;
        for (Integer key : actions.keySet()) {
            Action action = actions.get(key);

            if (action.pressed)
               action.speed = Math.min(action.speed + dt, 1);
            else if (action.speed > 0)
                action.speed = Math.max(action.speed - dt, 0);

            float dir = key == KeyEvent.VK_W || key == KeyEvent.VK_D ? 1 : -1;
            
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W || key == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
                y += Math.sin(r) * action.speed * dir;
                x += Math.cos(r) * action.speed * dir;
            }
            
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A || key == KeyEvent.VK_D)
                r += action.speed / 30 * dir;
        }
        t = millis;
    }

    Rect() {
        t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        new Timer(11, new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                repaint();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        f.add(rect);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.addKeyListener(rect);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        act(e, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        act(e, false);
    }

    void act(KeyEvent e, boolean state){
        Action action = actions.get(e.getKeyCode());
        if (null != action)
            action.pressed = state;
    }
}
```

Upd: Я сделал движение вперёд и назад, в направлении в котором "смотрит" прямоугольник и поворот, однако сейчас перечитал вопрос и понял что вы хотели не так, а проще, поворот по стрелкам...  ну вы уже, я надеюсь сами с этим справитесь, общий смысл не изменится.