# как отменить итерацию метода paintComponent

Tags: java, swing

если я начинаю делать циклы в методе "paintComponent", то метод начинает повторяться несколько раз. мне надо выполнить цикл отрисовки моего решения один раз. т.е. что бы метод "paintComponent" отработал один раз.

пауза "sleep" в метод добавлена временно показать что метод делает итерации

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class myWin extends JFrame {

    //взятие размеров экрана в пикселях
    Dimension sSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ().getScreenSize ();
    final int SCREEN_WIDTH = sSize.width;//ширина экрана (моя 1920)
    final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = sSize.height;//высота экрана (моя 1080)

    final static int SIZEX = 400;//ширина рабочего поля окна
    final static int SIZEY = 400;//высота рабочего поля окна
    final int BORDERS = 16;//ширина бордюров (8+8)
    final int HEADING = 39;//высота заголовка и бордюра (31+8)
    private int widthWin = SIZEX+BORDERS;//ширина окна
    private int heightWin = SIZEY+HEADING;//высота окна
    private int middleX = (SCREEN_WIDTH-widthWin)/2;  //поиск
    private int middleY = (SCREEN_HEIGHT-heightWin)/2;//середины экрана

    public myWin(){

        setTitle("numberTheory");//заголовок окна
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);//запретить растягивать окно
        setSize(widthWin,heightWin);//размеры окна
        setLocation(middleX,middleY);//координаты верхнего левого угла окна
        add(new numberField());//добавить объект класса
        setVisible(true);//сделать окно видимым
    }

    //головной метод
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myWin mw = new myWin();
    }
}

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class numberField extends JPanel{
    private int numcoil = 15;//число витков спирали
    private int arrX = (numcoil-1)*2 + 1;//кол-во столбцов
    private int arrY = (numcoil-1)*2 + 1;//кол-во строк
    private int[][] arrbas;// = new int[arrX][arrY];//базовый массив
    private int[][] substrate = new int[arrX][arrY];//дубликат массива arrbas - подложка
    private int middleX = myWin.SIZEX/2;//поиск
    private int middleY = myWin.SIZEY/2;//середины поля
    private int summa = 0;

    //конструктор
    public numberField(){

        arrbas = initArraySpir(numcoil);//спиральный массив в arrbas
}

    //определение координат с наименьшим числом при 8 ходах шахматного коня
    public int[] knightMove(int x, int y){

        int[] arr1 = new int[2];//arr[0] - координата x | arr[1] - координата y
        int[] arr8 = new int[24];
        arr8[0] = x-1; arr8[1] = y-2; arr8[2] = arrbas[arr8[0]][arr8[1]];
        arr8[3] = x+1; arr8[4] = y-2; arr8[5] = arrbas[arr8[3]][arr8[4]];
        arr8[6] = x+2; arr8[7] = y-1; arr8[8] = arrbas[arr8[6]][arr8[7]];
        arr8[9] = x+2; arr8[10] = y+1; arr8[11] = arrbas[arr8[9]][arr8[10]];
        arr8[12] = x+1; arr8[13] = y+2; arr8[14] = arrbas[arr8[12]][arr8[13]];
        arr8[15] = x-1; arr8[16] = y+2; arr8[17] = arrbas[arr8[15]][arr8[16]];
        arr8[18] = x-2; arr8[19] = y+1; arr8[20] = arrbas[arr8[18]][arr8[19]];
        arr8[21] = x-2; arr8[22] = y-1; arr8[23] = arrbas[arr8[21]][arr8[22]];
        arr1[0] = arr8[0];
        arr1[1] = arr8[1];
        int min = arr8[2];
        int s = 2;
        //
        for(int i = 2; i < 24; i+=3){
            if(substrate[arr8[i-2]][arr8[i-1]] != 1) {
                if (arr8[i] < min) {
                    min = arr8[i];
                    s = i;
                }
            }
        }
        arr1[0] = arr8[s - 2];
        arr1[1] = arr8[s - 1];
        return arr1;
    }

    //заполнение спирального массива
    public int[][] initArraySpir(int nc){

        int[][] arr = new int[(nc-1)*2 + 1][(nc-1)*2 + 1];
        int x = nc-1;//центральная ячейка массива
        int y = nc-1;//по координатам x, y
        int counter = 1;
        arr[x][y] = counter;

        for(int i = 1; i < nc; i++){
            x++;
            counter++;
            if(y >= 0){
                for(int j = 0; j < i*2; j++){
                    arr[x][y] =counter;
                    y--;
                    counter++;
                }
                y++;
                x--;
                for(int j = 0; j < i*2; j++){
                    arr[x][y] =counter;
                    x--;
                    counter++;
                }
                x++;
                y++;
                for(int j = 0; j < i*2; j++){
                    arr[x][y] =counter;
                    y++;
                    counter++;
                }
                y--;
                x++;
                for(int j = 0; j < i*2; j++){
                    arr[x][y] =counter;
                    x++;
                    counter++;
                }
                x--;
                counter--;
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }

    @Override//метод вывода данных в окно программы
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setPaint(Color.GREEN);
        int numberСours = 4;//число ходов
        int d = 15;
        int[] arr = new int[2];
        int x, y;
        arr[0] = numcoil-1;
        arr[1] = numcoil-1;

        for(int j = 0; j < numberСours; j++){
            substrate[arr[0]][arr[1]] = 1;
            x = arr[0];
            y = arr[1];
            arr = knightMove(arr[0], arr[1]);
            g2d.drawLine(x*d, y*d, arr[0]*d, arr[1]*d);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        g2d.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.drawRect((numcoil-1)*d, (numcoil-1)*d, 0, 0);
        super.repaint();
     }
}
```

Comment: вы что-то не так делаете, добавляйте код в вопрос...

Comment: мне теперь новый вопрос задавать и ждать 40мин.? потому как я не могу в комменты отправить код слишком длинный

Comment: под вопросом есть кнопочка - править

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Вашем коде как минимум 2 серьезные ошибки:

1. Вы зовете `super.repaint()` внутри `paintComponent()`, делать этого не нужно, Swing сам вызывает этот метод, когда компоненту необходима перерисовка, вызывая его во время перерисовки, вы порождаете бесконечный цикл.
2. Вы использовали `thread.sleep()` внутри `paintComponent()` это замораживает GUI поток.

Внутри `paintComponent` должен находится только код отрисовки, вся логика(изменение состояния) должна выполнятся не в GUI потоке. т.е. не в методе `paintComponent`

Недавно писал подобный код в ответ на другой вопрос: 
[управление отрисованным прямоугольником с клавиатуры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/946444/%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B/946487#946487)

Comment: получается метод "knightMove" не может быть внутри "paintComponent" и его необходимо решить каким-то образом вне. например собрать все нужные координаты в один массив в отдельном методе. но ведь результат вывода координат всё равно придётся зацикливать в "paintComponent" или я чего-то не понимаю? как отрисовать всё одним разом? super.repaint() и thread.sleep я закомментировал

Comment: @padLa repaint надо звать только тогда, когда что-то меняется в модели, т.е. есть смысл перерисовать

Comment: убрал repaint и вытащил метод наружу. всё получилось спасибо!

Comment: @padLa рад помочь, обращайтесь