# Легкий путь анимирования java

Tags: java, swing, canvas

В университете дали задание смоделировать морской порт. У него есть 5 станций обработки, каждая работает в своем потоке параллельно. С задачей модуляции я справился, а вот с анимированием нет. Никогда этим не занимался и даже не знаю куда копать. Нужно сделать простейшую анимацию из разряда - станции это квадраты, а корабли прямоугольники. Но нужно сделать так, чтобы очередь на обработку отображалась на экране, корабли в ней стояли, а когда приходила их очередь передвигались на зону обработки, а затем уплывали за экран. Подскажите как и где это будет лучше и удобнее всего сделать, ну и если есть примеры, был бы очень рад.
[Ссылка на проект](https://github.com/Exortigen/Seaport1.1).

P. S. Окно со статистикой сделано на Swing.

Спасибо!

Comment: Привет!
Возможно этот плейлист тебе поможет [ссылка](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lxzvpt4SMJw&list=PLwVvOVLAoKQl84bk2aCtkZgfb0qvq6ZHA&index=2)
Если тебя интересуют только квадраты и прямоугольники, то пропусти урок по растровой графике. Остальное думаю ты сможешь прикрутить из своего проекта. Здесь главное поймёшь как работает движок.

Comment: Чтобы сделать анимацию необходимо и достаточно добавить к состоянию время, и при перерисовках его учитывать - например у корабля есть вектор движения, и координата на экране, и в каждом кадре, чтобы посчитать новое положение корабля - необходимо посчитать сколько времени прошло с прошлого кадра, умножить вектор движения на дельту времени и прибавить в координате в прошлом кадре

Comment: вот откопал анимацию на swing из старых ответов - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/946487/188366